# in Django, cannot delete object because view is not updatable

Tags: sql-server, django

I have a model called Fiche which contains charfields and a couple of foreign keys. When I try to delete one row:

```
f = Fiche.objects.all()[0]
f.delete()
```

I get the following error:

```
('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]View or function 'entites_pilefusion_bFiche' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables. (4405) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

That view is partially based on Fiche okay but I should be able to delete one row of Fiche, no? Actually, when I try to delete the same row directly in SQL Server, I have no problem.

The problem is new, it seemed to appear after I add a new field in Fiche.
I have no idea how to solve or even trace the problem. I'm completely lost , any help would be much appreciated.
Patrick

EDIT: I solved the problem by adding in the model definition of PileFusionFiche (that is based on my view entites_pilefusion_bFiche) the clause *on_delete=models.SET_NULL* to avoid the ON DELETE CASCADE behavior on my view.

```
class PileFusionFiche(models.Model):

entite = models.ForeignKey('entites.Entite')
fiche  = models.ForeignKey('docentites.Fiche',blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'entites_pilefusion_bFiche'
    managed = False
```

Thanks again @Bistabil.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your problem appeared after you added a field from another table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Paragraph about updatable views is what interests you.

You need a INSTEAD OF trigger to be able to affect multiple tables with a view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Bistabil. I'll try the INSTEAD OF trigger and post the result (and you're right, the field I added was a foreign key). But one question: if it's a SQL error, how come it was possible to delete the row in Fiche directly in SQL Server?

Comment: You can perform any DML action on a table that doesn't violate constraints in your database, ie. you can delete any rows that aren't referenced by foreign keys. View doesn't introduce those constraints; it doesn't hold a reference to your underlying table, it's just a subquery of your data. Also, DML statements can only affect one table at a time and by deleting from a view that joins tables, you're trying to delete from multiple tables with one statement, which SQL doesn't support. Only views you can directly delete from are partitioned views (simple views that show a part of a table).

Comment: But the Fiche model refers to a table, so basically I'm trying to delete one row from a table, not from a view. And it does not work.

Comment: Look at your database views and inline functions. Somewhere in there you have a object 'entites_pilefusion_bFiche' which is a view of your Fiche table. The view is obviously a subquery of multiple tables which makes it read-only and data modification is blocked by SQL. `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'entites_pilefusion_bFiche' AND TYPE IN ('IF','V')` if you don't know where to find these objects, try this query to verify that a object like that exists. If you didn't create it yourself, Django did it for you.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Bistabil. I know this view, I created it myself (sorry if I was not clear about it). My point was that I'm trying to delete a row from the table Fiche and it has nothing to do with the view. The delete statement is possible in SQL Server but not from Django (Fiche.objects.all[0].delete() causes a database error).

Comment: It seems to me you've bound your controllers on the view and not on the table. It works from SQL server because you're deleting directly from the table, while it doesn't work from Django because you're trying to delete the data via the view. You wouldn't get this error msg from SQL server otherwise.

Comment: How can someone bind controllers on a view? I didn't try to delete the data via the view in django, I got an object from the Fiche table and tried to delete it.